# GTK 3 with Glade Button not working

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, glade

Using Glade to try and create a user interface. so far I have a main window and a sub window. I can click on a button on the toolbar of the main window to open an instance of the sub window class. I then have a button on the sub window that doesn't seem to be working

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class InitialWindow:

def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print("quit with cancel")
    Gtk.main_quit()

def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
    print("quit from menu")
    Gtk.main_quit()

def on_toolbutton5_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    print("Getting stock check")
    StockCheck()

def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "test.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.initialwindow = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.initialwindow.show()
    self.initialwindow.maximize()


class StockCheck:

def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "test.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.stockCheck = self.builder.get_object("stockCheck")
    self.stockCheck.show()

def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    print("worked")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = InitialWindow()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: _I ... have a button on the sub window that doesn't seem to be working_ - Can you describe what you mean by _not working_? You idea of not working can be very different from someone else's.

Comment: yeah sorry. so the button when pressed should print "worked" to the console (2nd function in the StockCheck class. but nothing is comin up on the console. I am not getting any error messages. Just no text in the console

Comment: Please also show `test.glade`.

Comment: I've never used a GtkBuilder, but I noticed you're calling `builder.connect_signals` for the main window, but not for the sub window...?

Comment: Yeah I tried adding builder.connect_signals into the stockcheck class but it was throwing errors. I will upload test.glade file

Comment: Managed to get it working. used builder.add_objects_from_file to add just the window required into each class then connected signals in both with builder.connect_signals(self)

Also moved the button clicked function above the def __init__(self) function in the stock check class